# Django: Do not allow users to see pages when login details do not match with custom models details

Tags: python, django, url, authentication, view

I have custom model where login details have been stored:

```
class UserRegistration(models.Model):
    # Auto updated when data is inserted
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    # Auto updated when data is altered
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

urls.py is

```
url(r'^login/$', view.login_page, name='login_page'),
```

views.py is

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "login_page.html")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print username, password
        credentials_matches = False  # considering credentials are wrong

        all_users = UserRegistration.objects.all()
        for user in all_users:
            if user.username == username and user.password == password:
                credentials_matches = True
                break

        if credentials_matches:
            return HttpResponse('success')
            # return redirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/lmtech")
        else:
            return HttpResponse('fail')
```

I have other views that I do not wish to show to user if they have not logged in. I though about @login_required() but in this case, user details are in custom model. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You **must not** make a custom user model like this. Writing your own authentication system is always insecure.

You should use the standard built-in auth framework - you can substitute your own user model but it must inherit from AbstractBaseUser, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). However there doesn't seem to be much reason to do this as you don't add any custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

On your custom model, you want the first name, last, name, username and password, in User model from django you only have the email more which is optional. So what you can do is to créate a User with the django's model and then use a relationship to have the two other attributes you want.

Here is an example

```
class User(models.Model):
  username = models.CharField()
  password
  ...

class UserMore(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  created_at = ...
  updated_at = ...

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In this case you then can use the `@login_required()` of django.
Personnaly, it's how I do.

But if you really want to keep your custom model without the User model of Django, maybe you can keep the user in a session that you initiate in your login view and then in your logout you delete it. In this way you can easily check if the `request.session['username']` is defined or not.